# Run gradle and create docker image on same machine with GitHub Actions

Tags: docker, gradle, github-actions

I have a VPS server, where docker is running. Also I have some branch with spring boot gradle app on github. And I am trying to create some release action, that will do 2 steps:

1. Build an executable jar with gradle
2. Create image with this jar on docker

Something like this:

```yaml
name: CD with docker

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "release" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "release" ]

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted

    steps:
    - name: Build with Gradle
      uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@v2
      with:
        arguments: clean bootJar
        gradle-executable: /opt/gradle/gradle-8.1.1/bin/gradle
    - name: Update Docker image & container
      run: |
        docker rm -f bta_backend
        docker rmi -f test/my-app
        docker build -t test/my-app .
        docker run -d --name bta_backend test/my-app
```

Problem is that it runs gradle, does some build in a temp folder, and starts post build cleanup, before docker from the 2nd step will create some image from it. I want or to chain this 2 actions, if possible, or combine them, as one. To run docker cleanup, after docker commands.

Comment: You are running docker container in the detached mode (background). Maybe, that's why it exits right away. Seems like it's doing the right thing as configured. Did you verify this with `docker ps` command?

Comment: there is no problem with docker, problem, that when step 'Build with Gradle' finishes, it starts cleanup and deletes .jar, required for docker image, before it is used

Comment: According to https://github.com/gradle/gradle-build-action#gradle-execution, "**If the action is configured with an `arguments` input, then Gradle will execute a Gradle build with the arguments provided.**". Did you try removing that `clean` in the `arguments`?